# Replacing " " by "_" with RegEx

Tags: regex, perl

I am using the Perl-Timestamp `localtime(time)`
The Problem is, I can work with blanks in variables, therefore I tried this:

```
sub ScriptCall()
{   
    my $SystemTime =  localtime(time);
    $SystemTime =~ s/ /_/; #replace every blank in $localtime by an underline
    print("Time : $Libname \nTime : $SystemTime \n");
#   Systemcall to activate the Script
    system("MyTestSkript.pl -date $SystemTime");
}
```

Sad thing is, it won't work.
Is my Regular Expression wrong or do I have a Bug in those few lines?

Comment: What do you mean by *“it won't work”*?

Comment: That it won't replace the blanks by "_"

Comment: But you said in a comment below that your output is correct when you add a `print` statement. What makes you think it isn't working?

Comment: Ah, I think you got me wrong. No it is still not working, the _At least i know that my RegEx is working_ was meant to his answer _Your regex works for me_ . I wrote that i got the same output 2 times, even if I add a print to control it.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand. But presumably if you run Avinash Raj's code it works fine for you? I think you simplified your code before you put it in your question, and in the process removed the problem. Can you show more of the *real* code please? And you really shouldn't accept an answer if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: I added a few lines, but showing the whole Module would take several hundred lines, therefore i just took the routine with the bug. That's my problem atm, not even this Code worked, therefore i am trying to find a bug in my settings. And yeah, sorry, I changed it.

Comment: That's okay. So you don't need help any more ay present?

Comment: Nah, thanks, I think I test my code on another Pc if I have the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna try adding a `g` to you RegEx, so it works global, and not only once

```
sub ScriptCall()
{   
    my $SystemTime =  localtime(time);
    $SystemTime =~ s/ /_/g; #replace every blank in $localtime by an underline
    print("Time : $Libname \nTime : $SystemTime \n");
#   Systemcall to activate the Script
    system("MyTestSkript.pl -date $SystemTime");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex works for me. I just added the print function to print the contents of variable `Time`  before the regex replacement and  after the replacement.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $Time = localtime(time);
print "$Time\n";
$Time =~ s/ /_/g;
print "$Time\n";
```

**output:**

```
Tue Nov  4 14:12:26 2014
Tue_Nov__4_14:12:26_2014
```

Comment: `Time : Tue Nov  4 09:55:55 2014` ||
`Time : Tue Nov  4 09:55:55 2014` Well,I get the same output 2 times..At least i know that my RegEx is working, thanks so far ;)